# Strange error using Editor control from ajax control toolkit

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

When trying to use the editor control i'm getting the following error:

```
    Value cannot be null or empty.
    Parameter name: elementID
```

Here's my HTML:

```
    <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor"
    TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
        <cc1:Editor ID="Editor1" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using asp.net 4 with ajax control toolkit for version 4.

I believe the error is talking about the routing I have. Is there something special I have to do if I want to use the toolkit and custom routing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that I was telling the framework to not rewrite my control Id's. In web.config I had the clientId mode set to static instead of predictive.

Comment: I ran into the same problem. You can set the ClientIDMode on just the Editor control if you want to leave your web.config as-is.